nginx error php8.3fpm upstream timed out on local server
2024/08/29 02:05:25 [error] 3313#3313: *153 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 194.233.87.73, server: website.ca, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock", host: "website.ca"

This is the error i get.
Ran ps aux | grep php-fpm and got this:
root         950  0.0  0.4 250300 37716 ?        Ss   00:34   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data    1462  0.0  0.8 326060 72344 ?        S    00:34   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data    1463  0.0  0.4 251024 36836 ?        S    00:34   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data    1561  0.0  1.1 350532 93664 ?        S    00:34   0:02 php-fpm: pool www
www-data    1566  0.0  0.4 251024 39816 ?        S    00:34   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data    1572  0.0  0.3 251024 25956 ?        S    00:35   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root        3215  0.0  0.0   3684  1792 pts/0    S+   01:47   0:00 grep --color=auto php-fpm

checked for pid by running the command ps -e
950 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm8.3

checked status with systemctl status php8.3-fpm.service
php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php8.3-fpm.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-08-29 00:32:57 UTC; 2h 2min ago

the site.conf server block in nginx is as follows:
location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }

I also checked to see if my server was being overworked and ran top
%Cpu(s):  9.5 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 72.4 id, 16.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7937.7 total,   6379.7 free,    814.6 used,   1012.3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   7123.1 avail Mem

It doesn't appear to be overworked.
This issue started occurring at midnight. I have committed no changes to any files and have no cronjobs I'm aware of that would suddenly execute. The server configuration was working great and then it didn't. The only logs that is left is the nginx log from above from what I'm aware of.

Bump* need answers.
